# Kibana discover no results found

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-x-pack

I have installed elk stack with x-pack feature, and shipping logs with filebeat. Everything is looks good , i was able to see logs in kibana -discover  last night and this morning i logged into kibana and can't see any single log. it showing as no result found i used same index pattern which is used in last night

Then again i shipped some logs with filebeat those are appeared in kibana and after 1 hour time those are disappeared i can't see logs again ? can anyone suggest what's happening

Comment: Are you sure that you have selected the right time frame at the top right of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at an index with a date field, I adjusted time range with timepicker button in the top right corner of your screen. it's working good

Comment: There you go !!